# Leetcode problem #21. Merge Two Sorted Lists SWIFT SOLUTION

Tags: swift

I am very new with the leetcode problems. I am prepping for interviews that will require me solving these problems and I didn't realize how hard the easy ones are. Anyways here is the question to the problem I have been working on.

You are given the heads of two sorted linked lists: `list1` and `list2`.

Merge the two lists in a one sorted list. The list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists.

Return the head of the merged linked list.

Example 1:

```
Input: list1 = [1,2,4], list2 = [1,3,4]
Output: [1,1,2,3,4,4]
```

Example 2:

```
Input: list1 = [], list2 = []
Output: []
```

Example 3:

```
Input: list1 = [], list2 = [0]
Output: [0]
```

Constraints:

- The number of nodes in both lists is in the range [0, 50].
- -100 <= Node.val <= 100
- Both list1 and list2 are sorted in non-decreasing order.

Here is the solution:

```
class MergeTwoSortedLists {
    func mergeTwoLists(l1: ListNode?, _ l2: ListNode?) -> ListNode? {
        let dummy = ListNode(0)
        var node = dummy
    
        var l1 = l1
        var l2 = l2
    
        while l1 != nil && l2 != nil {
            if l1!.val < l2!.val {
                node.next = l1
                l1 = l1!.next
            } else {
                node.next = l2
                l2 = l2!.next
            }
            node = node.next!
        }
    
        node.next = l1 ?? l2
    
        return dummy.next
    }
}
```

I understand most of this code. The dummy part is what throws me off. Can someone please explain what the line `let dummy = ListNode(0)` is doing please? Thanks!

Comment: you need the definition of the `ListNode` type and the `list1` type in order to do this problem.

Comment: Who wrote this solution? They're almost certainly not a seasoned Swift developer. The combination of `l1 != nil` with `l1!` in the loop (instead of just using conditional binding like `while let l1 = l1.next, let l2 = l2.next`) is quite out of place.

Comment: That solution is throwing you off because it's badly written. It would be better to call that variable `result` instead of `dummy`. Essentially it's a list, initialized to one element (`0`) to which you are merging the two lists. The `return` of `dummy.next` just skips the first element.

Comment: The `dummy` was created with a single purpose to return its `next` at the end of the loop, which will contain the *real* head of the merged list. But this is not a great solution, and most definitely doesn't use Swift as a language like someone said above.

Comment: @cora I started leetcode problems two days ago, I am here because I am trying to get better. Thanks for the useful comment!

Comment: What is it about the line `let dummy = ListNode(0)` you don’t understand? In itself the code is very basic so I guess that is not what you are asking about?